# How to get an intersection in venn_matplotlib between lists?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have two lists with more than 1000 string data.

2000 common data was found between them, according to the venn diagram.

Is there any possibility to get this intersection to the list?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Python has `set` object that does set operations.

```
A = {'0', '2', '4', '6', '8'}  # create set A

B = {'1','2', '3', '4', '5'}   # create set B

A.union(B)  # {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '8'}

A.difference(B)  # {'0', '6', '8'}

B.difference(A)  # {'1', '3', '5'}

A.symmetric_difference(B)  # {'0', '1', '3', '5', '6', '8'}

A.intersection(B)  # {'2', '4'}
```

If you already has a list of string:

```
listA = ['0', '1', '3', '5', '6', '8']
```

you can create a set object from it:

```
setA = set(listA)
```

If you require graphic representation of the results of sets' operation, please state clearly. Some effort on your side should be presented, or someone will mark your question `off-topic`.